# Angular 8. UnicoComponent > getSpecCharacteristicDescription > should be called TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

Estaba desarrollando una App en Angular 8 con TypeScript como lenguaje de Script, y me ha surgido el siguiente error testeando uno de los componentes.
Actualmente llevo unos 5 meses desarrollando en Angular 8, y es el primer contacto que tengo con JavaScript ya que anteriomente me dedicaba al desarrollo movil nativo en Android con Java.

El error que me vierte Karma, es el siguiente:

```
UnicoComponent > getSpecCharacteristicDescription > should be called
TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
```

El archivo spec.ts es el siguiente:

```
describe('UnicoComponent', () => {
  let component: UnicoComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<UnicoComponent>;
  beforeEach(() => {
    const tarifasServiceStub = () => ({});
    const detalleTarifasServiceStub = () => ({});
    const routerStub = () => ({});
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
      declarations: [UnicoComponent],
      providers: [
        { provide: TarifasService, useFactory: tarifasServiceStub },
        {
          provide: DetalleTarifasService,
          useFactory: detalleTarifasServiceStub
        },
        { provide: Router, useFactory: routerStub }
      ]
    });
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(UnicoComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });
 fdescribe('getSpecCharacteristicDescription', () => {
       fit('should be called', () => {
         const productSpecification = {
           productOffering: {
               productSpecification: { id: '' },
               bundledProductOffering: [{ id: '' }],
           },
           productSpecificationMobiles: [
               {
                   ospExternalCode: '',
                   productNumber: '',
                   ospMorganeCode: ''
               },
               {
                   ospExternalCode: '',
                   productNumber: '',
                   ospMorganeCode: ''
               }
           ],
       };
         const spy = spyOn(component, 'getSpecCharacteristicDescription').and.callThrough();
         component.getSpecCharacteristicDescription(productSpecification);
         expect(component.getSpecCharacteristicDescription).toBeTruthy();
         expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
       });
     });
 });
```

Y el código del componente como tal es el siguiente:

```
 getSpecCharacteristic(productSpecification) {
    return productSpecification.productSpecCharacteristic.filter(charact => !charact.productSpecCharacteristicValue);
  }
  getSpecCharacteristicOspLanding(productSpecification) {
    const product = productSpecification.productSpecCharacteristic.filter(charact => !charact.productSpecCharacteristicValue);
    return product.length > 0 ? product[0].ospUrlLanding : '';
  }
  getSpecCharacteristicDescription(productSpecification) {
    const product = productSpecification.productSpecCharacteristic.filter(charact => !charact.productSpecCharacteristicValue);
    return product.length > 0 ? product[0].description : '';
  }
```

Espero puedan ayudar si saben por donde van los tiros,  si es así, muchas gracias de ante mano!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ese error indica que se esta usando la función filter sobre algo que no existe
Es decir, estas declarando este objeto:

```
const productSpecification = {
           productOffering: {
               productSpecification: { id: '' },
               bundledProductOffering: [{ id: '' }],
           },
           productSpecificationMobiles: [
               {
                   ospExternalCode: '',
                   productNumber: '',
                   ospMorganeCode: ''
               },
               {
                   ospExternalCode: '',
                   productNumber: '',
                   ospMorganeCode: ''
               }
           ],
       };
```

Y en la función, accedes a productSpecification.productSpecCharacteristic, el cual no existe en tu objeto.

En javascript si accedes a un atributo que no existe en un objeto, no da error, por ejemplo

```
const obj = {
 nombre: 'Juan'
}

obj.nombre // devuelve 'Juan'
obj.atributoInventado // devuelve undefined y no da error
obj.atributoInventado.filter(loquesea) // devuelve el error que ves, ya que intenta ejecutar filter(o cualquier función) sobre undefined
```

Espero que te sirva

Un saludo!

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario! Probaré a ver si funciona.